# Read and write to a file in Amazon s3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I need to read a large (>15mb) file (say `sample.csv`) from an Amazon S3 bucket. I then need to process the data present in `sample.csv` and keep writing it to another directory in the S3 bucket. I intend to use an AWS Lambda function to run my java code.

As a first step I developed java code that runs on my local system. The java code reads the `sample.csv` file from the S3 bucket and I used the `put` method to write data back to the S3 bucket. But I find only the last line was processed and put back.

```
Region clientRegion = Region.Myregion;    
AwsBasicCredentials awsCreds = AwsBasicCredentials.create("myAccessId","mySecretKey");    
S3Client s3Client = S3Client.builder().region(clientRegion).credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(awsCreds)).build();    
ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse> s3objectResponse = s3Client.getObject(GetObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key("Input/sample.csv").build());    
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3objectResponse));    
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s3Client.putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key("Test/Testout.csv").build(),RequestBody.fromString(line));
}
```

Example: sample.csv contains

```
1,sam,21,java,beginner;
2,tom,28,python,practitioner;
3,john,35,c#,expert.
```

My output should be

```
1,mas,XX,java,beginner;
2,mot,XX,python,practitioner;
3,nhoj,XX,c#,expert.
```

But only `3,nhoj,XX,c#,expert` is written in the `Testout.csv`.

Answer (score 5):

The `putObject()` method creates an Amazon S3 object.

It is not possible to append or modify an S3 object, so each time the `while` loop executes, it is creating a new Amazon S3 object.

Instead, I would recommend:

- **Download** the source file from Amazon S3 to local disk (use `GetObject()` with a `destinationFile` to [download](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest-java.io.File-) to disk)
- **Process** the file and output to a local file
- **Upload** the output file to the Amazon S3 bucket ([method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-))

This separates the AWS code from your processing code, which should be easier to maintain.

Comment: Read the file into memory/buffer and then process it on the fly within the lambda and then write the modified/manipulated data back into s3. As mentioned by above, the putObject is writing only the last line to s3.

Comment: and if the local file is on a AWS Elasticbeanstalk -TomCat container,
is this the same way how to do?

Comment: @DuracellDeMonaco Please create a new Question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.

Comment: As per above, you cannot append or modify an S3 object.

One option is to use the AWS Storage Gateway.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/11/aws-storage-gateway-provides-a-file-interface-to-objects-in-your-amazon-s3-buckets/